# Loading data from repeater in asp.net in content slider?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am creating a content slider in which information is fetched from table in asp.net's repeater control. I am able to load data but when page gets load it doesn't give me frequent way of loading. Later this starts to get load smoothly but very first it show the all value containing in `DataSet` and those are shown one upon other.

**language: lang-js**

```
$("#slideshowinfo > div:gt(0)").hide();
            setInterval(function () {
                $('#slideshowinfo > div:first')
                
                  .fadeOut(1000)
                  .next()
                  .fadeIn(1000)
                  .end()
                  .appendTo('#slideshowinfo');
                
            }, 10000);
```

**.aspx Page**

```
<div id="templatemo_banner_content">
                            <div id="slideshowinfo">
                                <asp:Repeater ID="rptrNewsUpdates" runat="server">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                <div>
                                   <div class="header_01"><asp:Label ID="lblNewsHeading" runat="server" Text='<% #Eval("OrgName") %>' /></div>
                                   <p><asp:Label Id="lblNewsDescription" runat="server" Text='<%# string.Concat("Last Date:  ",Eval("Last Date"),"<br/>","Total Post: ",Eval("TotalPost"),"<br/>","Eligibility: ",Eval("Eligibility"),"<br/>","Description: ",Eval("description")) %>' /></p>
                                    <div class="button_01"><asp:LinkButton ID="linkReadMore" runat="server" PostBackUrl='<%# Eval("url") %>'>Read more</asp:LinkButton></div>
                                </div>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:Repeater>                             
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

**.cs Code Behind**

```
rptrNewsUpdates.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
rptrNewsUpdates.DataBind();
```

**Output rendered on user's screen**
[image]

Comment: You seem to have a client-side issue rather than server-side. aspx is most probably OK while your CSS (and from what I see probably js) isn't. When your page is loaded, the repeater has already ended its job (server-side), your CSS and javascript must take care of the correct client behaviour. Also, about UX, you might want to read [this](http://shouldiuseacarousel.com/)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I would recommend using an existing jQuery Slide Show plugin, I've modified some of your code to achieve what you're essentially looking for. I also made it possible for you to have multiple slide shows on the same page (be aware, though, that they will rotate at the same time). I wouldn't consider the JavaScript code modifications I've provided to be production-grade, but they demonstrate the point. Take note of the fact that I've added a bit of CSS to make sure that the initial visibility of the slide shows panes are as they should be right at the load of the page. You'd need to modify a bit of your Repeater code to account for the fact that I'm pre-populating the class attribute of the first pane of a slide show (you need to make sure the class attribute is populated *physically* on the page.

In what I've provided, I've stripped out your ASP.Net code to make my example clearer.

Here's the code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <!--these style rules should be moved to a separate file -->
  <style type="text/css">
    .slideshow .pane {
      display: none;
    }
    .slideshow .pane.active {
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <!--
  This JS code should be moved to a separate file, and its purpose is simply to be instructive for answering the question
  by refining the JS supplied in the question.

  This modified code is not production grade.

  Assumptions:
  -If multiple slide shows on a page, they rotate at the same time
  -No slideshow controls.

  -->
  <script type="text/javascript">

  (function($) {

    setInterval(function () {
        var fadeSpeed = 1000;

        $(".slideshow").each(function(){
          var $this = $(this);
          var $activeSlide = $this.find('div.active');
          var $nextSlide = $activeSlide.next();

          if($nextSlide.length == 0) {
            $nextSlide = $this.find("div.pane:first");
          }

          $activeSlide.fadeOut(fadeSpeed, function() {
            $(this).removeClass("active");
            $nextSlide.fadeIn(fadeSpeed).addClass("active");
          });


        });


    }, 10000);

  })(jQuery);

  </script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Slide Show Example</h1>

  <div id="templatemo_banner_content">
    <h2>Slide Show 1</h2>
        <div class="slideshow">
          <!--insert ASP.Net Repeater code here in order to output each pane based on data in the datasource -->
          <div class="pane active">

              <div class="header_01">Org Name 1</div>
               <p>Description 1</p>
                <div class="button_01"><input type="button" value="Read More" /></div>
          </div>
          <div class="pane">

              <div class="header_01">Org Name 2</div>
               <p>Description 2</p>
                <div class="button_01"><input type="button" value="Read More" /></div>
          </div>

        </div>

      <h2>Slide Show 2</h2>

      <div class="slideshow">
        <!--insert ASP.Net Repeater code here in order to output each pane based on data in the datasource -->
        <div class="pane active">

            <div class="header_01">Org Name 3</div>
             <p>Description 3</p>
              <div class="button_01"><input type="button" value="Read More" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="pane">

            <div class="header_01">Org Name 4</div>
             <p>Description 4</p>
              <div class="button_01"><input type="button" value="Read More" /></div>
        </div>

      </div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I have tried your code. Your code is working fine and thanks for the same. But I still have little confusion that how to decide which pane would be active and which to be not because I need to bind my label's with datasource so I have no clue how to set it active or not.

Comment: `<!--other slideshow code omitted for brevity-->
        <div class="slideshow">
            <asp:Repeater ID="ctlRepeater" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div class="pane <%# Container.ItemIndex == 0 ? "active" : String.Empty %>">
                        <!--other slideshow-related code omitted for brevity-->
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </div>`

Comment: Take notice of the check I'm doing on the index for each item do determine whether to output "active" in the class attribute of each slide show pane. If the index is 0, then I output "active", otherwise I output nothing.

Comment: I've abbreviated my example to make the example clearer. Obviously, you'll want to integrate what I have into the rest of the solution I provided originally.

Comment: Lastly, I'm assuming you're using C# for your implementation. If you're using VB.net, then the syntax for checking the index would be different.